# Implementing a robit model

Tags: expectation-maximization, robust, probit

I am trying to implement a robit model.  The answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114184/is-there-a-binomial-regression-model-that-captures-data-with-fat-tails) has a description.

I currently have functioning code (written in R) that follows the procedure laid out in this [paper](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~chuanhai/teaching/Stat598A/robit.pdf).  It looks like this:

```
1. Input data y, X, beta, nu
2. [E step] Calculate sufficient summary statistics
3. Update beta based on (2)
4. [M step] Find nu that maximizes the likelihood given y, x, and beta from (3)
5. Assess convergence based on the change in likelihood
6. Return to (1) if necessary
```

However, I do not think I have the correct implementation.  On page 9, the author says:

> Then update nu using, for example, the half-interval method

The paper seems to be saying there is an intermediate step after (4) where a different nu is used as the update (based on the half-interval method?).  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/links/Rnews.pdf) Koenker article? (*Parametric Links for Binary Response*). It contains R code. I think what you are looking for is also refereed to as The Gosset link (that's how I remembered it and that's how Koenker calls it, so you might try that). Finally, the R Package ‘glmx’ has some tools related to what you seem to be looking for (alternative links for logistic). Including the Gosset link.

Comment: @user603 thanks for the link.  i did come across the glmx package but did not make the connection between the t-distribution and the Gosset link.